# Can't put id on Widgets - Kiy

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I'm trying to put id's on my buttons, but I keep running into errors.
Here is my code

```
        self.layout.add_widget(Button(text = base[index], size = (50, 50),
                                 background_color = (.3, .3, .3, 1),
                                 id = 'button',
                                 #on_release = self.background_color = (0, 40, 1, 1) ,
                                 size_hint = (1, None)))
```

And I get this error

> TypeError: object.**init**() takes exactly one argument (the instance
> to initialize)

Is id supposed to be a string or what? If somebody can help me by explaining how ids work on Kivy I would be grateful

Answer (score 0):

I think the `id` property may have been removed in kivy master, which you might be using. However, this is because that property never did anything (it is *not* the same as ids in kv language), there is no loss of functionality.

If you want to give your Button a string identifier, create a Button subclass with a property for that.

Comment: How do I exactly do that? I'm trying to create a function where you can delete the button. But for that I need to identify that button. So can you help me a little bit?

Comment: You don't need to give the button a string identifier attribute in order to delete it. Provide a minimal example demonstrating the problem. Probably ask it as a new question, as this one has been answered.,